# How can I protect some pages dynamically?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a list of videos. Fews are public, and others private. These ones have login and password but it's not a single login/pwd, all private videos have their own protection. For the moment :

```
class VideoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/videos", name="videos")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $videos = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CcTestBundle:Video')->findAll();
        return array('videos' => $videos);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/video/{videoId}", name="video_show")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function showAction($videoId)
    {
        $video = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CcTestBundle:Video')->find($videoId);
        if($video->isSecured()) {
            **????**
        }
        else return array('video' => $video);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/video/{videoId}/login", name="video_login")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function loginAction($video)
    {
        **????**
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/video/{videoId}/login_check", name="video_security_check")
     */
    public function securityCheckAction($videoId)
    {
        **????**
    }
}
```

I don't know how to do, how to use forward and redirect actions. Could you help me ?

Comment: for redircts do `return $this->redirct(...)`

Where do you store you credentials now? On the Video Entity?

Comment: The "right" way to do this would be ACLs, I think.

Comment: I just need to implement login form, but I don't know how to do that, redirecting, forwarding and else.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar need to protect image files on a website I run.

What I did was put the files I wanted private in a subdirectory with `chmod 700` permissions and then used an if statement to call a function that generates a `DATA URI` which reads the file from the web inaccessable directory, encodes the file as Base64 on the fly and inserts the resulting Base64 encoding into the PHP page to be read by the browser.  I don't know how well this will work with videos due to their size, but here is the function.

```
function data_uri($file, $mime) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $base64 = base64_encode($contents);
    return "data:$mime;base64,$base64";
}
```

Then I just call the function where I want the picture.

```
<input class="map" name="pos" type="image" src="<?php echo data_uri("./img/overlay_$sessionid.png", 'image/png')?>" />
```

You just need to change your file types accordingly.